# Родственные ли слова "холка" и "холить"?

Tags: этимология

Пока писала вопрос об удилах, возник другой, тоже связанный с лошадьми.
У животных (не только у лошадей) есть такая часть тела - холка, бугорок на стыке шеи и спины. Обычно в холке измеряют рост.
А есть слово "холить" - хорошо заботиться, баловать.
Интересно, это просто похожие слова или все-таки родственные?

Answer (score 1):

Одно из определений:
ХОЛКА. Искон. Суф. производное от холить, ср. терка от тереть. Холка буквально — "часть шеи лошади, которую холят, чистят, гладят, за которой ухаживают в первую очередь". 
Так что вполне возможно, что родственники.

Answer (score 1):

**холка**
**1.** *анат.* ***часть шеи, смежная с хребтом.***
 ◆ *Бирюк молча взял лошадь **за холку** левой рукой: правой он держал вора за пояс.*
 И. С. Тургенев, «Бирюк», 1848 г.
**2.** ***Шерсть, грива, растущая на этом месте.***
 ◆ *Лев Николаевич подходит к лошади, как опытный кавалерист, с головы, берёт, правильно подобрав, повода́ в левую руку и, выровняв их **у гривы на** **холке** и захватив вместе с поводами **пучок холки**, берёт правой рукой левое стремя.*
 И. Е. Репин, «Далёкое близкое», 1912–1917 г г.

**холить**
***Заботливо, с большим вниманием ухаживать за кем-либо, чем-либо.***
 ◆ *А я буду так лелеять, **холить тебя,** любимое, больное дитя мое!*
 М. Е. Салтыков-Щедрин, «Противоречия», 1847 г.
◆ *Он и одеваться стал модно, дорого. **Холил** свою тёмную остренькую бородку, брил щёки и всё более терял простое, мужицкое.*
 Максим Горький, «Дело Артамоновых», 1924—1925 г.

*А.Н.Тихонов в "Словообразовательном словаре русского языка"* (1990) относит эти два слова в совершенно разные словообразовательные гнезда:

**127. *холить*** (+ещё  19 слов)
**128. *холк(а), холочка***

Это позволяет предположить, что слова ***"холка"***  и  ***"холить"*** *не* *являются родственными, однокоренными*, а просто — ***очень похожи***.

Думаю, что можно спокойно сказать (без тавтологии): ***хол***ить **хол**ку (как и хвост, как и круп, как и копыта), а также ***хол***ить **хол**опа,  ***хол***ить [и лелеять новый] ***хол***одильник, **хол**ить **хол**остяка.